# Is there any extension available for Wechat share in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, social-buttons

Is there any Magento 2 extension available for wechat share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched on the internet to find possible solution on this, but didn't get what I want.

Instead of searching for wechat share integration you can use [**AddThis**](https://www.addthis.com/) plugin. It will give you range of share buttons. They also worked on Wechat share, so after embed this **you can see WeChat share too**.

**Note:** We chat share will only appear on mobile browser, because it's a mobile APP, and you wont see it on desktop. But you can test it on browsers' mobile view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer....! Work like a charm..!

Comment: That's great. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you check these? I have not

```
https://marketplace.magento.com/silksoftwarecorp-wechatlogin.html
https://www.sunflowerbiz.com/magento2-wechat-pay
```

Comment: I don't need wechat payment gateway, I want we chat share just like whatsapp share..! Thanks for your answer..!